# Deleting a line in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am drawing a grid by drawing lines using some loops one for columns and the other for rows.
But I want to delete a line based on if a condition is met.
Is there a way of deleting a line after its drawn?
.I've thought about making an array of line objects then removing the object but that didn't work basically..
Is there a way of deleting a line after its drawn? Thanks.

The code shown is the loop which draws the horizontal lines.

```
 for(int j = 0; j < rows; j=j+30)
    {//Iterate through rows
        //              Color choice = chooseColor(rectColors);
        //Method that chooses a color

        line = new Line(0,j,rows,j);
        //Create a new line(startY,startX,endx,endy)

        line.setStroke(Color.GREEN);


        pane.getChildren().add(line);
        //Add line to board

    }
```

Comment: `pane.getChildren().remove(line)` or `removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`.

Comment: Hi yeah that works but it only removes the outer line . Is there a way of uisng indexes to remove the intended line?

Comment: You can also call `pane.getChildren().remove(index)`...

Comment: You asked: _Is there a way of deleting a line after its drawn?_ Do you mean that first you draw the line, then you decide if you need it or not?

Comment: I'll try what Zevphr said. And yeah basically eventually it's going to be a maze generator using a binary tree algorithm so I want to remove one of the walls when needed.

Comment: You only keep track of a single line. This way you can only remove this line without knowing the index of the line you want to remove. You need to keep track of the lines one way or another. Deleting part of a line is not possible tough (at least not in a reasonable way). If you only want to delete the section of the line between intersections with two ortogonal lines (which is what I'd expect from a maze generator), you need to implement this in a different way...